# jQuery syntax added var

Tags: javascript, jquery

I needed a jQuery function to fix my div when the page is scrolled.

I found this:

```
var fixed = false;
var topTrigger = $('#sticker').offset().top;
$(document).scroll(function() {
    if( $(this).scrollTop() >= topTrigger ) {
        if( !fixed ) {
            fixed = true;
            $('#sticker').css({'position':'fixed', 'top':'0'});
        }
    } else {
        if( fixed ) {
            fixed = false;
            $('#sticker').css({'position':'relative'});
        }
    }
});
```

Now, since I'm not a super beginner with jQuery, I tried to skim it and understand it. The only things I don't understand are the things related to the `var:fixed`. I tried to delete the var and the if statement related to that and the function works perfectly.

**My question** : why is that variable there, what does it mean, what feature does it add to the entire function?
Why should I keep it there instead of deleting everything related to that variable?

Comment: It is just a flag used to check whether the `position` property is fixed.

Comment: Just a double check? Just in case the position is not already changed by something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scroll event will be fired multiple times as the user scrolls. If you keep on changing the DOM attributes, then the performance of the site may slow down.

To avoid applying the style multiple times, they are having a flag called `fixed`. So once the user has scrolled a particular height, they will trigger change the DOM to be fixed. Later they need not again change the CSS style.

Only if the user scrolls back less than the threshold they need to change the style again.

Comment: So, with such a flag I'm not changing the DOM each time i trigger the function? How come is that?

Comment: Initially the flag is `false` and once the user scrolls and crosses the threshold set by `sticker` it will set the DOM position to be absolute. Later even if the user scrolls down there is no need to reapply style to be absolute as it's already absolute.

Comment: So, without the flag each pixel my user scrolls, it will keep changing the DOM. Is that what you're saying?

Comment: I just found out that with the flag thing it only does it once. If I scroll back to the top then down again, the menu doesn't become fixed anymore.

Comment: Nope. If you see in the else condition they're checking if the flag is true/false. If it's true then they are resetting it to false. So i don't see as a problem